# Ajax response passing parameters into URL bar (get?)

Tags: jquery, ajax

Can anyone help me debug this simple function.
I am using an onclick event to submit the form.  It passes the $id parameter into the function.

```
<input type='Submit' name='Submit' id="Submit" value='Add' class='btn btn-success' onclick="PostForm(<?php echo $id; ?>)">
```

The problem occurs in the response of : if (response == 2). (edit: actually i have noticed I am not receiving a resposne, but an auto refresh which populates the URL bar with GET Parameters)

In Chrome browser the page reloads as it should using the location.reload().
However, when in Firefox/IE it is passing the parameters to the URL bar, for example ..url/500?id=500$other_field=1000 rather than reloading the page.

What could be the problem between the browsers that are making this happen?  The function simply calls a local .py script, so nothing to cross domains is happening.

```
<script>

function PostForm($id) {

  var isValidForm = $("#form_id").valid(); //checks form is valid
  if (!isValidForm) {
      return false;
  }
  else {

  var id= $id; //store id

  $('.btn').attr("disabled", true); //disable buttons

  //waiting popup code

  $.blockUI({ css: { 
      border: 'none', 
      padding: '25px', 
      backgroundColor: '#111111', 
      '-webkit-border-radius': '10px', 
      '-moz-border-radius': '10px', 
      opacity: .5, 
      color: '#fff' 
  } }); 

  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'xxx.php',
    data: $('#form_id').serialize(),
    success:function(response) {
        if(response == 1) {
          alert("Script executed successfully.");
          window.location.href = "/xxx/" + id;
        }

        else if(response == 2) {
          alert("Script failed to execute");
                   location.reload();
        } 
   }

  });

} //end else
} //end function
```

Comment: Try appending timestamp to the URL. So that each time, a unique URL is submitted.

Comment: actually I have noticed I am not getting a response.  Somewhere after the POST the page is also refreshing and populating the url bar with GET paramaters

Comment: I can now hit the alert("Script failed to execute") prompt, however in Firefox/IE the browser instantly refreshes and the url bar has the GET parameters

Comment: Haven't found a direct answer to this, I decided to user a submit handle instead, rather than an onclick function.  Not sure which is the best.